# AWS Lambda function cannot import the Lambda layer module created using AWS CDK TypeScript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am building a serverless API using API gateway, Lambda and CDK. I am using TypeScript for both lambda functions and CDK. Now, I am trying to create a simple lambda layer and try to re-use it in my Lambda function. But, when I invoke my lambda function, it's complaining that, it cannot import the module (lambda layer).

I have a simple Lambda function with the following code.

```
import { add } from "/opt/nodejs/calculator";
import {APIGatewayProxyHandler} from "aws-lambda";

export const calculate: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event) => {
    const result = add(1, 2);

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: `1 + 2 = ${result}`
        })
    }
}
```

The filepath of the function's file is `{root}/api/src/handlers/layer-lambda.handlers.ts`. As you can see in the code, it's importing `add` function from `/opt/nodejs/calculator` module which is the lambda layer.

For lambda layer, I created a file under the path, `{root}/api/src/layers/calculator/nodejs/calculator.js`. This is the content of the file.

```
export const add = (num1: number, num2: number) => {
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

And this is the `{root}/api/src/layers/calculator/nodejs/package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "calculator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

I also configured the paths for lambda layer in the `compilerOptions` section of the `{root}/api/tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      // other settings
      "paths": {
      "/opt/nodejs/calculator": [
        "src/layers/calculator/nodejs/calculator"
      ]
    }
   }
}
```

Then in the CDK I created the Lambda function with Lambda layer like this.

```
const layerVersion = new LayerVersion(this, getStageSpecificResourceId(`calculator-layer`), {
            compatibleRuntimes: [ Runtime.NODEJS_18_X ],
            compatibleArchitectures: [ Architecture.X86_64 ],
            code: Code.fromAsset(path.resolve(__dirname, `../../api/src/layers/calculator`)),
            description: `Simple calculator lambda layer`,
        });

       const calHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, `calculate`, {
           entry: path.resolve(__dirname, `../../api/src/handlers/layer-lambda.handlers.ts`),
           functionName: getVariantSpecificResourceId(`calculate`),
           handler: `calculate`,
           memorySize: 1024,
           runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
           timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
           bundling: {
               sourceMap: true,
               minify: false, // TODO: set to true for production
               externalModules: [ `/opt/nodejs/calculator` ],
           },
           environment: {},
           layers: [
               layerVersion,
           ],
       });

       this.api.root.addResource("calculate").addMethod("GET", new LambdaIntegration(calHandler));
```

You can see that I am setting the `externalModules` field of the lambda as `[ '/opt/nodejs/calculator' ]`. The reason is that if I set it as `[ 'calculator' ]`, it does not throw error when the function is invoked, but the lambda layer code is also included in the lambda function's code. Basically, it's not using the lambda layer. With the current implementation, when I invoke the function, I am getting this error.

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/calculator'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/calculator'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/index.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Commenting because I have the same exact issue